# Itertools Combinations Error / Memory problem

Tags: python-3.x, memory, combinations, python-itertools

I am a Finance graduate student and new to Python. I have to create a list of possible combination of 500 stocks for a school project. (In nCr terms, I need 500C2, 500C3, ..., 500C498, 500C499, 500C500)

I have the following code:

```
    tickers = list of the 500 stocks I'm using

    import itertools

    w = len(tickers) + 1 
    i = 2
    test_list = []

    while i < w:
        combinations = list(itertools.combinations(tickers,i))
        test_list.append(combinations)

    i = i + 1

print(test_list)
```

However, I get the below error when running the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: `test_list` holds _a heck of a lot of values_ and you're trying to dump all of that into your notebook. This may very well crash it, so the server has taken measures to prevent this from happening. The values are there, so you can print the first few entries just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are 500! / (250! * 250!) = 116744315788277682920934734762176619659230081180311446124100284957811112673608473715666417775521605376810865902709989580160037468226393900042796872256 =~ 1.1674431578827768e+149 combinations of 250 out of 500 stocks, let alone 500C251, 500C252, etc., so naturally your computer memory isn't able to accommodate this large a number of items when you try to append them all into `test_list`.

So whatever calculations and/or I/O operations you're trying to do with the combinations, do them directly inside the loop and do not store the combinations in a list. But then again, this is such a large number of combinations that you will likely have a hard time finishing the loop in a lifetime even if the loop did nothing. You should rethink your approach to the problem you're trying to solve.